# ANOVA: do I interpret the significant main effects not involved in interactions?

Tags: anova, interaction

My statistical model is `Dependent ~ A * Sex + B * Sex`. (i.e., `Dependent ~ A + B + A:Sex + B:Sex`). I have prior reason to expect that `Sex` will interact significantly with `A` and `B`, but no reason to expect that `A` and `B` will interact. When I run my data, I get these results.

- `A` (significant main effect)
- `B` (not significant)
- `A:Sex` (not significant)
- `B:Sex` (significant interaction)

That is, there is a significant main effect of `A`, and an interaction between `B` and `Sex`. My understanding of ANOVA is that since `B:Sex` is significant, I need to segregate the data by the levels of one of the factors (I will choose `Sex`) and test the effect of `B` on each subset separately. But, should I interpret the main effect of `A` before doing that? Or should I segregate the data, and retain the independent variables `A` and `B` in the test for each subset?

Comment: instead of segregating the data, you should fit a model with A, B, Sex and B*Sex as covariates. (why there is no Sex in you model? A*Sex means sex in the model.)

Comment: Oh, I was using R notation, so A * Sex means A, Sex, and the interaction of A and Sex.

Comment: Did you have any a priori hypotheses about which of the two interactions you would expect to be significant? Did you power your study to be able to detect significant interactions?

Comment: Yes, I believe both interactions could be significant, and there plenty of power. :-)

Comment: Are A and B continuous variables in your model?

Comment: A and B here represent several more variables. Most are categorical, but two of them are numeric (integers).

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear from your question whether you are still engaged in model selection, or whether you have settled on your model and are now only interested in interpretation of the outcome.  In view of the description, I am going to assume that you are still undertaking model selection, and you are interested in comparing the present model with one that removes the interaction of `A` and `Sex`.

In these kinds of models it is generally a bad idea to monkey with the data to try to segregate it.  It is much simpler just to fit the two nested models of interest and then use a standard goodness-of-fit test comparing the nested models to see if there is any evidence to include the extra parameters in the larger model.  In your case, the comparison of interest is between these nested models:

`Model 1:  Dependent ~ A + B + Sex + A:Sex + B:Sex`

`Model 2:  Dependent ~ A + B + Sex + B:Sex`

It should not be difficult to calculate the goodness-of-fit statistics for these two models and then perform a comparison, noting that `Model 2` is nested within `Model 1`.  This would usually be done with a chi-squared test comparing the log-deviance of the models.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately I intended the former option: I have my model, an am just trying to interpret the results correctly. I've edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: If you have already fit your model, and you're happy with that model, then no issue of data segregation or additional testing arises.  You just take the outputs of that model and interpret them in the normal manner for regression coefficients.  Presence of conditional statistical associations can be done by using the T-tests in the output.

Comment: When I learned to do ANOVA (not in a statistics department), it was presented as standard practice that, when an interaction arises, one divides the data by the levels of one of the factors and does another ANOVA on the subsets (also here, which I found as a sanity check: https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-tutorial-series-two-way-anova-with-interactions-and-simple-main-effects/) Is that not the case?